# can't see website after deploying a .war file to tomcat

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

I have created a java web application and created the file thymeleaf.war to deploy it on a tomcat server.

I access the tomcat manager using www.lux-systems.com/manager/html and have uploaded the thymeleaf.war file on this page.

Now i can see /thymeleaf in the application list, but when i click on that link (www.lux-systems.com/thymeleaf) I only see the directory listing instead of the web-page I want to see.

The problem is that I can't find the url to the working web page, and I am wondering why www.lux-systems.com/thymeleaf is only showing the directory listing.

Comment: Did you check the tomcat logs?

Comment: @Vawani https://pastebin.com/RN9ARUn3 these are the logs, i have no clue if i can find the error in here.

Comment: You are using Spring, Spring boot?

Comment: Is the directory listing containing the same files as your web application?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen no, the files of my application are in another folder, but that folder isn't even visible in the directory listing.

Comment: What does the tomcat logs say about how the deployment went?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I found the problem but I can't find the solution. All the files are in the folder: WEB-INF. Here are all the java classes, controllers and html pages. How can i change this?

Comment: I Think you should add a very detailed description on how you ake your war file because that is what you need to fix.